# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/TestListener

Tags: junit, ant, eclipse-rcp, hudson

While running automated test cases for an RCP application, the following error was shown:

```
[java] Java Result: 13
```

And the stack trace is:

```
    !MESSAGE Application error
    !STACK 1
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/TestListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:272)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:632)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:588)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:527)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)

...

    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.framework.TestListener cannot be found by org.apache.ant_1.9.6.v201510161327
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 53 more
```

Junit.jar is already available in the classpath.

The Eclipse version which I used for RCP application is Eclipse 4.5.2 (Mars) and Junit version is junit 4.12.0 (org.junit_4.12.0.v201504281640). ANT version used is 1.9.6 (org.apache.ant_1.9.6.v201510161327)

Comment: Please note that it is [not urgent at all for volunteers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) here to attend to your issue. If they would like to answer it, they will do so at their leisure.

Answer (score 0):

There was some work done on an issue in Eclipse 4.5 (
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=485620).

Updating your Eclipse to 4.6 might help.

Comment: Is there no other way without updating eclipse to 4.6?

Comment: I don't know. just saying this might solve you issue and updating eclipse is mostly not a big deal.

Comment: I updated eclipse to 4.6.2, but I am still having the same error while running test cases from ant.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be an answer...

My experience was that for our PDE build for Eclipse 4.4.1, we were using `eclipse-test-framework-3.6`. When upgrading to Eclipse 4.6.2 I changed it to use `eclipse-test-framework-4.6.2` (downloaded from [4.6.2 - Eclipse Project Downloads](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.6.2-201611241400/)). This gave me another problem where the `org.eclipse.test_3.3.0/library.xml` file couldn't be found - needed for [this usage](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform-releng/Eclipse_Test_Framework#Interface) - so I just added the 3.6 test framework **and** the 4.6.2 test framework to the dropins folder of the Eclipse platform being used for our tests. We have two suites of tests and when running the second one it would give me the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.framework.TestListener cannot be found by org.apache.ant_1.9.6.v201510161327` exception. I guessed it was something to do with what plugins are added/resolved and their dependencies and configuration that gets cached for this. So I changed our ant test targets to clear the `eclipse/p2` and `eclipse/configuration` directories and take a fresh copy before running every suite. This is surely a total hack, but it seems to work.